# How to split a cell using only spaces and without period as delimiter

Tags: excel, vba, split, delimiter

I have a list of data with multiple IP addresses in a single cell.
I use comma delimiter to split the IPs into separate cells.

For Example,

| A |
| --- |
| 10.10.33.187 10.10.48.6 10.10.33.188 |
| 10.56.100.77 172.22.210.253 |
| 172.22.210.3 172.22.210.6 172.22.210.7 172.22.210.8 |

gets converted into,

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10.10.33.187 | 10.10.48.6 | 10.10.33.188 |  |
| 10.56.100.77 | 172.22.210.253 |  |  |
| 172.22.210.3 | 172.22.210.6 | 172.22.210.7 | 172.22.210.8 |

**However, when I run the code again, it also splits each IP into separate numbers.
Although the code does not use a period delimiter why does the IP address get split along the periods?**

For example,

| A |
| --- |
| 10.10.33.187 |

gets converted into,

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 10 | 3 | 187 |

I know that this can be done using simple excel function.
However, I need VBA code for a larger task of which this is just one step.
**So can someone please help me with preventing the splitting of period (full stop)?
Without a period delimiter why is it splitting it at the periods?**

```
Sheets("Hosts").Activate
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True
```

Comment: I would use find() with left() mid() and right() to split them. Hint: go for the spaces...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function

Comment: @braX thanks for the link. I had already checked it before posting here. It does not talk about period (".") as a delimiter. Since I don't use it in my code, I'm wondering why does my code split against periods.

Answer (score 4):

The [Range.TextToColumns method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.texttocolumns) has one issue, it likes to remember what was used last, to split. So if you includede a dot `.` to split at, in your previous `TextToColumns` actions even if it was in the user intarface only. Excel tends to remember that and use it.

To avoid that I recommend to specify all parameters of the method. The missing one here is `Other:=False` to ensure no other characters are used for splitting.

```
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False
```